OptaPlanner/TimeFold - FullAssert mode exception and constraint explanation
I am currently working on a project that requires scheduling tasks to resources while minimizing travel time between tasks assigned to the same resource. There are additional constraints, but this is the main objective.
I am running OptaPlanner in FULL_ASSERT mode and encountering the following exception:
Score corruption analysis:   The corrupted scoreDirector has 7 ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess (and should not be there):
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/First assignment as early as possible/[Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, [Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30]]=0hard/0medium/-8100soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/First assignment as early as possible/[Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, [Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30]]=0hard/0medium/-8100soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/First assignment as early as possible/[Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, [Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30]]=0hard/0medium/-8100soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/MatchSkill/[CheckPolicyCommand[assignmentId=73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4, task=Task{id=73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4}, resource=Resource{id=2}, interval=Interval[startDateTime=2024-06-18T09:30, endDateTime=2024-06-18T10:30], travelTime=TravelTime[startDateTime=2024-06-18T09:30, endDateTime=2024-06-18T09:30, duration=0], travelTimeToHomeBase=null, dependsOnAssignments=[]]]=-1hard/0medium/0soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/Minimize resource travel time/[Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, [Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30]]=0hard/0medium/-365soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/Minimize resource travel time/[Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, [Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30]]=0hard/0medium/-365soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/Minimize resource travel time/[Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, [Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30]]=0hard/0medium/-365soft   The corrupted scoreDirector has 7 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing:
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/First assignment as early as possible/[Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, [Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00]]=0hard/0medium/-8100soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/First assignment as early as possible/[Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, [Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00]]=0hard/0medium/-8100soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/First assignment as early as possible/[Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, [Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00]]=0hard/0medium/-8100soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/MatchSkill/[CheckPolicyCommand[assignmentId=73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4, task=Task{id=73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4}, resource=Resource{id=2}, interval=Interval[startDateTime=2024-06-18T09:30, endDateTime=2024-06-18T10:30], travelTime=TravelTime[startDateTime=2024-06-18T09:30, endDateTime=2024-06-18T09:30, duration=0], travelTimeToHomeBase=null, dependsOnAssignments=[]]]=-1hard/0medium/0soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/Minimize resource travel time/[Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, [Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00]]=0hard/0medium/-295soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/Minimize resource travel time/[Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00, [Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00]]=0hard/0medium/-295soft
com.optimization.fm.policy.scheduler.infrastucture.constraint/Minimize resource travel time/[Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, [Task ID: 73abb022-924f-40ac-a848-2a73ee7a0ab4 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:30, Task ID: d7e5f8a3-73b9-4f6c-9b12-96f4e13b70e0 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T10:00 | End: 2024-06-18T12:00, Task ID: 731c791d-7ea6-476b-afc7-77c632e062c7 | Res: 2 | Start: 2024-06-18T09:30 | End: 2024-06-18T10:00]]=0hard/0medium/-295soft
Maybe there is a bug in the score constraints of those ConstraintMatch(s).   
Maybe a score constraint doesn't select all the entities it depends on, but finds some through a reference in a selected entity. This corrupts incremental score calculation, because the constraint is not re-evaluated if such a non-selected entity changes. Shadow variable corruption in the corrupted scoreDirector:   None

Here are the constraints mentioned:
public Constraint firstAssignmentAsEarlyAsPossible(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(OPTask.class)
    .filter(OPTask::isResourcePresent)
    .join(OPTask.class)
    .filter(
        (task1, task2) -> task1.getResourceId().equals(task2.getResourceId()))
    .groupBy((firstTask, secondTask) -> firstTask,
        ConstraintCollectors.toList((firstTask, secondTask) -> secondTask))
    .penalizeConfigurable((task, list) -> (int) Math.pow(
        getUnassignedPeriodAfterBeginning(task.getResource().getAvailabilityCalendarId(), list),2))
    .asConstraint("First assignment as early as possible");
}

public Constraint minimizeResourceTravelTime(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory.forEachIncludingNullVars(OPTask.class)
    .filter(OPTask::isResourcePresent)
    .join(OPTask.class)
    .filter(
        (task1, task2) -> task1.getResourceId().equals(task2.getResourceId()))
    .groupBy((firstTask, secondTask) -> firstTask,
        ConstraintCollectors.toList((firstTask, secondTask) -> secondTask))
    .penalizeConfigurable((task, list) -> sumOfTravelTime(task.getResourceId(), list))
    .asConstraint("Minimize resource travel time");
}

public Constraint matchSkill(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {

    var matchSkillRule = OPRuleCache.getRule(RuleType.MATCH_SKILL);
    
    return constraintFactory.forEach(OPTask.class)
        .filter(task -> task.isResourcePresent() && task.isNewTask())
        .map(task -> OPRuleCache.createCheckPolicyCommand(task, task.getResource()))
        .filter(matchSkillRule::isViolated)
        .penalizeConfigurable()
        .asConstraint("MatchSkill");

}

When I switch to FAST_ASSERT mode, the exception does not occur, and a good solution is generated. However, I am unable to understand the issue in FULL_ASSERT mode.
The exception indicates the presence of expected and excess constraints, leading me to believe there might be a problem in the data grouping for constraint checks. However, I am unsure how to resolve this.
I suspect my understanding of FULL_ASSERT mode and Constraint Streams might be lacking.
I am seeking advice on how to resolve the score corruption issue. Is there a potential bug in the constraints' implementation, or could it be related to the scoreDirector's incremental score calculation? Any explanations, instructions, documentation, or tutorials that could help me understand and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.
Best regards.
